# How can I reduce the namespace qualifiers When using inner Enums?

Tags: python, enums

I'm using  Python 3.10.12.
When I use an inner `Enum`, my code has many redundant namespace qualifiers, and they require a lot of horizontal space. How can I reduce them? For example:

```
class Outer:
    class InnerEnum(Enum):
        INNER_VALUE_ONE = 1
        INNER_VALUE_TWO = 2

    def outer_method(self):
        # I'd prefer "some_local: InnerEnum = INNER_VALUE"
        some_local: Outer.InnerEnum = Outer.InnerEnum.INNER_VALUE_ONE  # Can I reduce the namespace qualifiers?
```

Comment: Don't bother with nested classes in the first place.

Comment: Why are isolating the enum, and not just having it at the module level?

Comment: I'm writing plugins for Gimp 3.0, and it's current behavior is that plugins can effectively be one single file. On the other hand, any global definitions might collide with any other plugin's globals, or perhaps anything the plugin infrastructure defines. It's all still under development.

Comment: "any global definitions might collide with any other plugin's globals" why would they collide?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I reduce the namespace qualifiers When using inner Enums?

Try this in my example.

Snippet:

```
from __future__ import annotations
import enum

class InnerEnum(enum.StrEnum):
    INNER_VALUE_ONE = '1'
    INNER_VALUE_TWO = '2'
    
    @property
    def outer_method(self) -> InnerEnum:
        return InnerEnum.INNER_VALUE_ONE if self is InnerEnum.INNER_VALUE_TWO else InnerEnum.INNER_VALUE_TWO

print(InnerEnum.INNER_VALUE_ONE)
print(InnerEnum['INNER_VALUE_ONE'])
print(InnerEnum("1").outer_method)
print(InnerEnum('2').name)
print(InnerEnum.INNER_VALUE_ONE.value)
print(InnerEnum.INNER_VALUE_ONE == 'INNER_VALUE_ONE')
print(isinstance(InnerEnum.INNER_VALUE_ONE, str))
 
for Inner_Enum in InnerEnum:
    print(Inner_Enum)
```

Output:

```
1
1
2
INNER_VALUE_TWO
1
False
True
1
2
```